# How to install CocoaPods mac 10.10.5

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods

Trying to install CocoaPods through the terminal. I copy and paste this into the terminal "sudo gem install cocoapods" The title of the terminal changes to say ruby. When I then navigate to my  file with my Xcode project through the terminal and type "pod init" it does not recognise the command so I don't think Cocoapods have been installed correctly. How can i fix this? I'm on OS 10.10.5

Comment: Read the manual carefully please! it should be `sudo gem install cocoapods` (also read the terminal output, look for errors!)

Comment: sorry was just typing it into the text window here an i added a space. I am in fact using 'sudo gem install cocoa pods'.